# Which topics and textbooks to learn elementary school arithmetic and beyond?

Tags: soft-question

I'm an adult who tries to learn math from the ground up in his free time.

I've decided to start with arithmetic, but I don't know where to go next. I'm a type of person who learns by reading. I want to understand math, not to memorize it.

What topics (starting from arithmetic and on) to study? In what sequence? Please recommend textbooks.

I know some very very basic things, such as addition, subtraction, and how to find square roots. My foundation in math is very poor. I can say, safely, that till yesterday, I didn't know what ones, tens, and hundreds are, what place value is, what points and coordinates are and a lot more.

Comment: Your arithmetic has to be solid. Things like tables and knowing how to do long division and fraction operations are a must. Then I would look for a pre algebra book (ebay, amazon etc) and begin with that. Also, Khanacademy is a good place to learn from in addition to your textbook.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibly useful old books that I've come across in a nearby library are:

Aaron Bakst (1900-1962), [**Arithmetic for Adults. A Review of Elementary Mathematics**](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/006198847), F. S. Crofts and Company, 1944, viii + 319 pages. [one amazon.com review](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007FMKR4)

Burdette Ross Buckingham (1876-1962), [**Elementary Arithmetic. Its Meaning and Practice**](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000163793), Ginn and Company, 1947, viii + 744 pages.

Interestingly, both seem to be freely available (legally also) on the internet. If you don't like lengthy on-screen reading, you can print out the pages (might have to do it one page at a time) or try to obtain a copy using interlibrary loan at your public library.

Regarding your question about what to study after arithmetic for high school mathematics, the subjects would be (elementary) algebra (typically a two year sequence), geometry, trigonometry, and precalculus (often includes trigonometry). Rather than worry about textbooks to use after arithmetic at this time, I would recommend that you focus on the task at hand -- arithmetic. In general, you'll find that the more you know, the more your previous plans wind up being changed because you begin to develop a better understanding for what approaches you like and you're better able to pick out books that function best for you (at these later times). I learned a lot of math on my own (most of high school math and all of the 3-4 semester college calculus sequence, and much of elementary linear algebra) simply by picking books from libraries and bookstores that I *liked* and that were books I felt I could learn from. The more I learned, the more I found that my own choices tended to be better for me than what others might have suggested, which often tended to be little more than what textbook *they* learned from rather than a reasoned choice from the thousands of available textbooks.