# I need a book for very very beginning of mathematics.

Tags: book-recommendation, math-history

In the book, I want to read what a number is, operations and their origins, what is the zero number, what it means to be a negative number, what does it mean to have a rational power of a number like 1/2 and so on.

Can you advice me such a book which may also contain proofs for each theorem?

Comment: Have you considered asking this question on the forum [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Related: [Which topics and textbooks to learn elementary school arithmetic and beyond?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1963961/13130) and [Books about elementary mathematics written like a good undergraduate textbook](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1857/745).

Comment: Try this-https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematics-Elementary-Approach-Ideas-Methods/dp/0195105192

Comment: @John_dydx I was about to recommend Courant and Robbins, but I see you beat me to it !

Comment: @gandalf61, it was the first book that came to mind.